# Dates in openldap acl rules

Tags: openldap, access-control

Is it possible to use dates in OpenLDAP's ACL entries?  I'm looking to do something like `to * by this/termDate < NOW none by * break`

Comment: not exactly a dba question if you ask me. Maybe this <http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ldap> is a better place to look?

Comment: [meta](http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/190/is-ldap-on-topic/191#191) thought it was on topic, so here it is

Comment: @ik_zelf : and this is *exactly* why a few of us complained about the name change.

Comment: so if I'm reading this correctly -- you're trying to set a termination date for the user, after which they no longer have access to do something?

Comment: @Joe - yeah that's the idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible within OpenLDAP.

When I've had to do something similar in the past, it was against an iPlanet/SunONE Directory Server, and we had a daily cron job that polled the payroll server for terminations, and then adjusted attributes as appropriate to lock the accounts.

The only approach I can think to try is if there's some way to get the equivalent of `NOW` in an ldap filter, so you could add a 'what' clause like:

```
filter=( termDate < NOW )
```

... but I don't know of any way to do that without some sort of external intervention to set `NOW`.